# Rapidly determining the final value returned by a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

One of the questions asked in an exam that I sat through yesterday got me fascinated.

```
int G(int n)
{
  if(n > 100)
  {
    return (n - 10);
  }
  else
  {
    return (G(G(n + 11));
  }
}
```

We were asked to choose the correct result of G(10) from four choices. I came back home, wrote the program on my PC and it spat out 91 as the answer. Indeed 91 was listed as one of the answers.

Determined to reach the same answer, I manually wrote an assembly program equivalent to get to the answer [Thinking there would at most 10-12 stack frames created before they all unwinded].

```
G:
 CMP R0,#100   [Register R0 has the argument. Also the return value.]
 BLT Label     [Branch if less than]
 SUB R0,#10
 RET

Label:
 ST R14, [SP]  [Store the return address of the caller on stack]
 SUB SP,#4     [Update the stack pointer]
 ADD R0,#11
 BL G          [G(n+11)] Uses value in R0 as argument, Returns value in R0 
 BL G          [G(G(n+11))] same comments as above 
 ADD SP,#4
 LD R14,[SP]
 RET
```

I then manually recreated stack frame for each invocation and the frames just kept increasing. At around 20 stack frames, I gave up.

Suspicious of my assembly program, I went ahead and inserted a counter in the C program and it indicated that the function had been entered 183 times.

Clearly this was a question meant to be solved in 5 minutes, so there has got to be a simpler solution like a thumb rule or a graph or something.

How would you have gotten to the answer in less than 5 minutes?

Comment: The reason there aren't only 10-12 stack frames is that it's not a standard recursive function definition, when it calls itself _once_. Because of the return line being `return (G(G(n + 11));`, each call actually spawns _2_ subsequent calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is G (n) if n > 100?

What is G (n) if n = 100?

What is G (n) if n = 99? (Use the answer above).

What is G (n) if n = 98? (Use the answer above).

...

What is G (n) if n = 90? (Use the answer above).

What is G (n) if n = 89? (Use the answers for n = 100 and n = 91).

And so on. There will be a very, very obvious pattern.

Comment: You made it so awfully simple gnasher729. So the trick was to build a lookup table for n= 100 through 111. And simply re-use those values for n=100 and below. I feel really dumb now. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: This makes sense since the only way for (G(G(n + 11)) to return a value is if `(G(n+11)) > 100 AND n <= 100`, but we need (G(n+11)) to return a value that means that `(n+11-10) > 100`. so the condition becomes `n+1 > 100 AND n <= 100` where n is an integer the only solution is n=100, that means that the only possible return value of the else branch is G(G(111)) = 91.

Answer (score 0):

Note that an optimizing compiler will rearrange the code a bit and generate a tail recursive loop:

```
G       proc
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]   ;n
        add     eax, 11
        cmp     eax, 100
        jle     SHORT G0
        add     eax, -10
        jmp     SHORT G1

G0:     push    eax
        call    G
        add     esp, 4
G1:     cmp     eax, 100
        jle     SHORT G2
        add     eax, -10
        ret     0

G2:     mov     DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax  ;n
        jmp     G                       ;tail recursion
G       endp
```